# PyQt4 QTextBrowser set text at the end

Tags: append, pyqt4

Dear stackoverflow community;

I've got a QTextBrowser widget, I set a text on it via QTDesigner, now I need to set another line of text to it via code.
My code:

```
self.ui.textStatus.append('text')
```

I don't find a working append method for a QTextBrowser object, any idea how to do so?

Kind regards;

Answer (score 8):

```
self.ui.textStatus.setText(self.ui.textStatus.text() + ' text')
```

Anyway, from what I can read in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html#append) `QTextBrowser` inherits from `QTextEdit` and it has the `append()` method (just tried in a dummy app)..